# FFmpeg: convert an image's raw binary data to audio format (for databending purposes)

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, image-editing, binary-files

[This article](https://www.hellocatfood.com/databending-using-audacity/) describes how one can mess with an image by converting its raw binary representation to audio PCM and applying audio effects to it, before converting back. The method it recommends is to import into Audacity, which has the option Import Raw Data for doing just that.

[image: Screenshot of Audacity's Import Raw Data menu]

Since I would like to do my audio manipulations in other software (namely Reaper, which doesn't have an equivalent option) it would be best if I could skip the Audacity step and simply throw a command at each image I'm working with.

This seems like something the FFmpeg CLI should be able to handle, but I have failed to turn up any guides on doing this and my own FFmpeg knowledge is pretty much limited to copy-pasting.

I tried `ffmpeg -i example.png example.wav` but got the output:

```
Input #0, png_pipe, from 'example.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1253x499, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Output #0, wav, to 'example.wav':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

I suspect if there is a way, it will involve some kind of stream manipulation, but for me that is the most confusing part of the ffmpeg interface. Can anyone help me out?

Bonus points if your solution works for converting the image stream of a video to audio too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## image to audio

You can output rawvideo and pipe it to another `ffmpeg` instance forcing the input as PCM audio:

```
ffmpeg -i in.png -f rawvideo - | ffmpeg -y -f s16le -sample_rate 44100 -channels 1 -i - -f s16le out.sw
```

- Adjust the demuxer and muxer formats with `-f`. Final output in this example is "s16le" (PCM signed 16-bit little-endian).
- See `ffmpeg -demuxers` and `ffmpeg -muxers` for as list of available demuxers & muxers.
- For details and options for a specific demuxer: `ffmpeg -h demuxer=s16le`
- For details and options for a specific muxer: `ffmpeg -h muxer=rawvideo`

If your audio editor doesn't accept raw PCM then you can try WAV. Since you're going to mess with it anyway it shouldn't matter much:

```
ffmpeg -i in.png -f rawvideo - | ffmpeg -y -f s16le -sample_rate 44100 -channels 1 -i - out.wav
```

## audio to image

```
ffmpeg -f s16le -sample_rate 44100 -channels 1 -i edited.sw -f s16le - | ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -pixel_format rgb24 -f rawvideo -i - out.png
```

YMMV. If PNG output doesn't work for you then experiment with other formats.

Comment: Thank you! This looks promising so far, although I'm having problems with then being able to read the output file in Reaper. I suppose file corruption is par for the course when attempting something like this, so I'll keep experimenting and hopefully can get it working before I accept your answer. Please note that the command to list available demuxers is simply `ffmpeg -demuxers` not `ffmpeg -h demuxers` (which results in 'Unknown help option')

Comment: @Igid Sorry, I'm not familiar with Reaper so I don't know what to suggest regarding that. I fixed the typo, thanks.

Comment: Reaper is just a sound editor. The output file also fails to play with Preview/VLC - what I mean is that it's corrupted as far as most audio applications are concerned.

Comment: @Igid See edits.

Comment: Sorry for the late response on this. I haven't had much time to experiment in depth with this yet but I appreciate your efforts to fill out your answer. I'm sure the problems I was encountering weren't to do with the correctness of your solution.